# How can I iterate over CopySpec in gradle, or even get the destination pathname of a file from the copyspec

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a Zip task which uses the CopySpec like DSL.Like:-

```
task1 {
    from(src/main/pig).exclude(<some file pattern>) {
        into "pigscripts"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is iterate over the pig scripts, as in if copySpec is the CopySpec object associated with it,

```
Map<String,String map> = new HashMap<String,String>()
copySpec.eachfile {
    map.put(it.originalpath,it.destinationpath)
}
```

However in this gradle discussion forum https://discuss.gradle.org/t/iterate-over-a-copyspesc/13030/6 it seems this is not straight forward.
It will also suffice if I can get the destination path of a single file since I can get a FileTree of all the source files as

```
FileTree filetree = (copySpec as CopySpecInternal).buildRootResolver().allSource
```

then i would like to do something like

```
filetree.each{
    //map.put(it,copySpec.findDestinationPath(it))
}
```